# Jsoup does not load full HTML content

Tags: java, jsoup

i am trying to  post a request with jsoup to this site:https://www.obi.gr/obi/Default.aspx?tabid=125 . This is the english version.However jsoup.connect does not return the complete html content.It sees to me pretty weird because when i posted a request to the greek version(greek version:https://www.obi.gr/obi/Default.aspx?tabid=124) i got the complete html content.

With the term "not return the complete content" i mean that there is missing html content and i can not make the web scraping.As i said before when i post something to greek version i get the complete html content and i can make my web scraping.

I hava several things like setting the timeout property or the maximum body size
or setting the headers however it all failed.

Here is my code:

```
String url1 ="https://www.obi.gr/obi/Default.aspx?tabid=125";
        Document doc = null;
        try {
        doc=(Document) Jsoup.connect(url1).
        data("ScrollTop", "appropriate value for the request body").
        data("__EVENTARGUMENT","").
        data("__EVENTTARGET","").
        data("__VIEWSTATE","appropriate value for the request body").
        data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR","appropriate value for the request body").
        data("__dnnVariable","appropriate value for the request bodyot>").
        data("dnn$SEARCH1$txtSearch","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$btnSearch","appropriate value for the request body").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$ddlPriorityCountry","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtApplDate","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtApplNumber","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtClassificationIpc","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtClassificationLocarno","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtEPOApplDate","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtEPOApplNumber","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtEPOPublDate","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtEPOPublNumber","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtGrantDate","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtInventionTitle","car").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtInventor","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtOwner","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtPatentNumber","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtPriorityDate","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtPriorityNumber","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtReceiptNumber","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtRepresentative","").
        data("dnn$UcEMTWrapper1$ctl00$txtSupplementaryCertificates","").
        userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36")

                .post();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        //an exception probalby will be cause if Obi changes its request body
        Logger.getLogger(JSoupWrapper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

Comment: Maybe english version does not have the section that greek one has. Did you check HTML in browser? Whats missing?

Comment: The missing section is a table which containt the content i need to scrape.So when i search for car both versions return a table with content i need to scrape.The only difference is that in english case that some information is in English.Everything else looks excactly the same